# Add an image button with transparent background

Tags: android, eclipse, background, transparent, imagebutton

I want to add image buttons on my main app screen that have a transparent background. I have created the images in GIMP and saved them with transparent backgrounds in png format but when I add them to my android app in Eclipse they appear with a white background. How do I remove this in my code?

Comment: if you view the .png in an image viewer, is the BG transparent? i'm questioning if you correctly created the image in GIMP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using null for the background for your image button in the xml layout.

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: Another way is to set the background to "#00000000" (full transparent) but "@null" is so much simpler...

Answer (score 0):

You can just set

```
android:background="@null"
```

in the XML

Answer (score 0):

A transparent background generally works when used in photoshop, if it is not, you have to set the alpha bits of the pixels around the border of your image

use **alpha-masking**( subset of alpha blending, google them to know more).

**A little theory:**   depending on the alpha bits for each pixel in your Bitmap (the translucency bits), the extent of blending of that pixel with over-written pixel is determined. Considering extremes, if alpha is 255, overwriting pixel is used instead of  the over-written one (**fully opaque**, in regular terms); if alpha is 0, overwriting pixel is just ignored (**transparent**). For other alphas in between: there is blending.

In your case you *would* have to make the alpha of the border **zero**, to achieve complete blend. Outlining all  the steps in geral:.

1. The drawable to be used **can't** be a JPEG( JPEG doesn't store alpha values per pixel). Go for PNGs

   2.You **will need** to create and keep your bitmap drawable in that way beforehand(use google for alpha blending PNGs) such that the borders have zero alpha value ( use softwares like Paint.NET for ex).
2. If images are being created dynamically, you would need to use a blending equation ( for details read materials by Porter and Duff).

   For ex, this is PNG image with transparent pixels having alpha 0 other than the alphabet itself
   .
   [image: original PNG with alpha blending]

[image: aplha blended PNG on colored background]

Above is the alpha blended PNG on colored background of an Activity. I hope this is what you really want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my .aspx page - adding an  that did an add to and remove from favorite functionality. I know the image was a .gif image format having a transparent background - but as mentioned here it showed in the browser in IE9 and Chrome, as a white squared background.

I added this and it solved the issue - but you must ensure the .gif or image indeed has a transparent background too:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="lnkFavorite" BackColor="Transparent" AlternateText="Add Favorite" CommandName="Favorite"
ImageUrl="Images/MakeFavorite_30.png" ToolTip="Click to add to the My Favorite Threads grid."
    CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") + ";" + Eval("FavoriteUserID")%>' />
```

The **BackColor="Transparent"** attribute did it for me! I hope that helps too!

Russ

Answer (score 0):

Answering here 5 years later for compatibility with Android L+.

In order to use a PNG (transparent) image as background on an ImageButton, you should use the property `background` instead of `src`

```
     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageProg"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:onClick="doStuff"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_stuff"
```